# Vue.js vue-test-utils How to test a watcher?

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

In my AudioPlyar component , a computed onAir() popery is defined

```
 computed: {
    onAir() {
      return this.autoplay && !this.playing && this.seek === 0 ? false : true;
    }
 },
```

And a watcher is defined on it :

```
  watch: {
    onAir() {
      if (this.onAir === false) {
        this.stop();
        this.$emit("playerStop");
      }
   }
  },
```

I am trying to test this watcher , but it's ailing ...

```
it("watcher onAir", () => {
  // given
  const wrapper = shallowMount(AudioPlayer, {
    propsData: {
      sources: ['require("@/assets/audio/ultimo_desejo.mp3"'],
      autoplay: true,
      loop: false,
      percentage: 0,
      playing: true,
      onAir: true
    },
    mixins: [VueHowler]
  });
  const spy = jest.fn();
  wrapper.vm.$on("playerStop", spy);
  // when
  wrapper.setData({ onAir: false });
  // then
  expect(wrapper.vm.onAir).toBe(false); // OK 
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // NOT CALLED ...
});
```

Any feedback welcome ...

Comment: I don't see a Vue instance being passed in to `shallowMount` options. Is this why the component does not react to the watcher's `$emit`?

Comment: Oops thanks for notice it ! Need to put my glasses on

Comment: Try wrapping your `expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` in a `wrapper.vm.$nextTick()` callback like:
`wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => { expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) })`